# Asynchronous iteration javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, iteration

The reset function resets a grid I have. The spotMaker function colors the grid. I want to run the reset function and wait until it is completed before the loop iterates. I tried several things with callback functions but still could not get it to run asynchronously.

```
for (walkthroughs; walkthroughs < numberOfWalks; walkthroughs++) {
  console.log("Walkthrough: " + walkthroughs);
  reset();
}
// Repeat for as many number of walk
function reset() {
  console.log("Walkthrough: " + (walkthroughs + 1));
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, dimensionX * 50, dimensionY * 50);
  ctx.fillRect(playerPositionX * 50, playerPositionY * 50, 50, 50);

  playerPositionX = 0, playerPositionY = (dimensionY - 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < dimensionX; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < dimensionY; j++)
      grid[i][j] = 0;
  grid[0][dimensionY - 1] = 1;

  maxX = 0, maxY = (dimensionY - 1);
  minX = 0, minY = (dimensionY - 1);

  i = 0;

  // Start the process
  spotMaker();

}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in explaining what exactly needs to happen?

Comment: So are you trying to synchronously control the async function? Also, which function in your code is aync? As far as I can tell, there is none at the moment.

Comment: The program let's the user enter dimensions for a grid. A dice is rolled and spots are filled depending on the number. Once the top right of the grid is color the program ends. The user is allowed to enter in how many times it runs, which is the numberOfWalkthroughs. 

My problem is that if there are 2 walkthroughs, the for loop will run the reset function twice and they will both be running at the same time. I want the function to complete before it runs again.